Consumed fn arg that can be owned or a ref in Rust
I would like to make a function that can take either owned value, or a reference that can be cloned into an owned value.  This way an owned value can be passed in without extra cloning.  It seems I am able to do it with a custom trait specifically for String/&str, but I couldn't find anything similar/generic in stdlib. Am this approach incorrect?
trait MyToString {
    fn to_owned_string(self) -> String;
}

impl MyToString for &str {
    fn to_owned_string(self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}

impl MyToString for String {
    fn to_owned_string(self) -> String {
        self
    }
}

fn foo<T: MyToString>(v: T) -> String {
    v.to_owned_string()
}

fn main() {
    let s_ref: &str = "hello";
    println!("{}", foo(s_ref));

    let s_owned: String = String::from("world");
    println!("{}", foo(s_owned));
}


The linked question has an additional Iterator wrapping the T/&T but you can just strip it.

@cafce25 thx, but the linked question is not the same -- I posted this q to Rust forums and got a much more in-depth and nuanced replies.  I really wish this type of answers happened here at StackOverflow :( https://users.rust-lang.org/t/consumed-param-that-can-be-owned-or-a-ref/110744

Feel free to add an answer with Into to the linked question⁉ If you feel your question is different please [edit] it to show how.
